# Standalone executables with mono on linux?

Tags: linux, mono

Using Mono on Linux, is there any way to create a standalone executable which will run on systems without mono installed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should take a look at the [mkbundles](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2004/Dec-01.html) command. It can static link all the required libraries and the CLR along with your app into one exe.

Also check out [this](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications#bundles) page on the different ways of running mono applications.